# WebStorm ESLint output window

Tags: window, webstorm, eslint

I have WebStorm with ESLint enabled and it's working fine.

But from VS Code I'm used to see the eslint output window for the whole project I'm working on, not only for the current file (and hidden inside the scrollbar)

[image: see the screenshot]

I cannot figure out how to do this in WebStorm - is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see all errors coming from ESLint in Inspection Results tool window that opens when you run Analyze/Inspect Code:

[image]